# Catching vertical scrolling on a horizontal ion scroll view

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework

I have horizontal scroll box like this codepen and it works fine. http://codepen.io/calendee/pen/HIuft

```
<ion-scroll direction="x" class="wide-as-needed">
        <a class="button inline-button">this is a button : 1</a>
        <a class="button">this is a button : 2</a>
        <a class="button">this is a button : 3</a>
        <a class="button">this is a button : 4</a>
        <a class="button">this is a button : 5</a>
        <a class="button">this is a button : 6</a>
        <a class="button">this is a button : 7</a>
</ion-scroll>
```

I have a couple of them in a long view that has vertical scrolling. The problem is when you're interacting with the horizontal box you can't do vertical scrolling which is annoying. Should I add Javascript code to catch the scroll event or ionicGesture and do the scrolling manually with js or is there a better workaround?

Comment: This is a 'feature' with a couple of work-arounds. See the long discussion about it here: http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/when-using-horizontal-scroll-ion-scroll-page-cant-be-scrolled-down-in-y-direction/3833/22 ... but yes the solution is to add more javascript which catches the vertical scroll event.

Comment: I was part of that discussion many months ago. If you use native scrolling it works fine but the js scrolling ionic relies on is awful and this is not the only problem it introduces. It's a really bad framework to do serious work with. I ditched it many month ago and I wouldn't recommend it to anyone. The only positive point about it is piggy backing on top of angular which itself is not a really powerful platform for mobile-first development.